# Will the 1.2.2 Gazebo version de one presented at Darpa Robotics Challenge Kickoff?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Next week will happen the Darpa Robotics Challenge Kickoff with a tutorial on the simulator that will be used during the challenge. Will the 1.2.2 Gazebo version de one presented at Darpa Robotics Challenge Kickoff or you guys got a special version for the event?

Best regards,

Luis Filipe Rossi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/67/will-the-1.2.2-gazebo-version-de-one-presented-at-darpa-robotics-challenge-kickoff?/) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Version 1.2.3 will be used at the kickoff

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0